# I have HTML files in the same folder but they don't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm having 4 files in the same HTML Folder on my local machine which is Jen_MoodBoard, and here is my code:

```
        <script>
            document.getElementById("outdoorPhotography").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "/Jen_MoodBoard/OutdoorPhotography.html";
            };
            document.getElementById("childAbusePrevention").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "https://preventchildabuse.org/";
            };
            document.getElementById("sfGiants").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "https://www.mlb.com/giants";
            };
            document.getElementById("fireSafety").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/user/FireKillsCampaign/videos";
            };
            document.getElementById("electroMusic").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "https://soundcloud.com/alltrapnation";
            };
            document.getElementById("snapCreation").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "https://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html#present:Username=eagledragon&ProjectName=BND_of_Doom";
            };
            document.getElementById("divLlama").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "/Jen_MoodBoard/Jen_Anime2.html";
            };
            document.getElementById("gameList").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "https://gamestarmechanic.com/workshop";
            };
            document.getElementById("citationsButton").onclick=function () {
                location.href = "/Jen_MoodBoard/Jen_Moodboard_Citations.html";
            };
        </script>
```

I linked them all in buttons with JavaScript, but when I tested with another computer, /Jen_MoodBoard/OutdoorPhotography.html, /Jen_MoodBoard/Jen_Anime2.html, and /Jen_MoodBoard/Jen_Moodboard_Citations.html led to pages saying

```
Your file was not found
It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I checked the links and they looked fine to me, but why do the links to my pages not work but the rest does? 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying the pages are on your local machine?

Comment: I don't know, but they're in the same folder and I created them on my school computer. It worked in my school computer but when I tested it here at home the links were broken

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running this without a server on your home machine and Jen_MoodBoard is not in your root directory. So you need to use relative paths instead. Without knowing your directory structure, I'm going to work with a couple of assumptions.

If the file with your above script is in the same directory (i.e. Jen_MoodBoard) as OutdoorPhotography.html etc.

Then change your links from "/Jen_MoodBoard/OutdoorPhotography.html" to "./OutdoorPhotography.html"

If the file with your above script is in a different directory than Jen_MoodBaoard
Then use the relative path to Jen_MoodBoard. 
e.g. "./Jen_MoodBoard/OutdoorPhotography.html"